# Busqueda en base de datos con Foreach en mi modelo Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hola a toda la comunidad stackoverflow, mis respetos para esta sitio sin duda esta lleno de genios y espero que me puedan ayudar :/ ...

El asunto aquí es que tengo que hacer un reporteo de cuantas personas fueron citadas por campaña desde el primero del mes hasta el día de hoy, eso lo estaba haciendo manualmente, cada que agregaban una nueva campaña yo agregaba manualmente otra función en el model buscando los citados con respecto a la campaña nueva...pero quiero optimizar el tiempo, haciendo una función que me facilite todo esto...

Les explicare como tengo estructurado mi código:

En mi controlador tengo esto:

```
$Nombres_campañas = $this->realreporteo->Nombres_campañas(); //Con esto obtengo los nombres de las campañas que existen.

if($Nombres_campañas != FALSE)
{
$result = array();

foreach($Nombres_campañas as $row) 
{
   $info = $row->empresa;
   $result[] = $this->realreporteo->Formula_numeros_citados($info);
}   

$data['resultados'] = $result;

}       


$this->load->view('headers/librerias');
$this->load->view('headers/menu-admin');
$this->load->view('reporteo', $data);
```

En mi modelo tengo las funciones asi

```
function Nombres_campañas() // Este es para sacar los nombres de las campañas
{ 
        $this -> db -> select('empresa,fechaent');

        $this -> db -> from($this->TableReporteo);  

        $this -> db -> where('fechaent >= ', strtotime(date('1-m-Y')), TRUE);
        $this -> db -> where('fechaent <= ', strtotime(date('d-m-Y')), TRUE);

        $this->db->group_by('empresa');

        $query = $this->db->get();


        $row = $query->result();

        return $row;

}
```

Este es mi función que debería de sacar el conteo

```
function Formula_numeros_citados($info)
{ 

        $this -> db -> select('empresa,fechaent,estatus');

        $this -> db -> from($this->TableReporteo);

        $this -> db -> where('estatus','Citado');

        $this -> db -> where('empresa',$info);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        $row = $query->row();

        return $row;

}
```

Y quiero que se pueda imprimir en mi vista en una tabla con un foreach

```
foreach($resultados as $value)
            {

             echo 
             '
             <tr>
                 <td>'.$value->empresa.'</td>
                 <td>'.count().'</td>
             </tr>
             ';

             }
```

Mi base de datos se llama reporteo y tiene campos básicos tipo varchar "nombre, empresa, fecha, campaña, estatus, telefono, etc etc..."

Actualmente el código que les mostré me arroja en mi vista un resultado así:
Si me arroja los nombres de las campañas pero el conteo me lo hace mal :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les agradecería muchisisisimo que pudieran ayudarme :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

espero que mis pequeñas sugerencias te sirvan

controlador

```
$nombre_campana     = $this->realreporteo->nombres_campanas();
$result         = array();//fuera del if para su validacion si el resultado es false

if( nombre_campana){
    foreach($nombre_campana as $item){
        $result[]   = array(
                    'company'   => $item->empresa,
                    'info'      => $this->realreporteo->formula_numeros_citados($item->empresa)
                    );
    }
}

$data['resultados]  = $result;
```

modelo

```
function nombres_campanas ( ) {
    $this->db->select('empresa, fechaent')
        ->from($this->TableReporteo)
        ->like('fechaent', date('m-Y'), 'both')
        ->order_by('id', 'asc');

    return $this->db->get()->result();
}

function formula_numeros_citados ( $info ) {
    $this->db->select('fechaent, estatus')
        ->from($this->TableReporteo)
        ->where('estatus', 'Citado')
        ->where('empresa', $info)
        ->order_by('id', 'asc');

    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

en la vista

```
$prin = '';
foreach($resultados as $item){
    $prin .= '<tr>'
        .'<td>' . $item->company. '</td>'
        .'<td>' . ( count($item->info) > 0) ? $item->info : 0 . '</td>'
        .'</tr>';
}

echo $prin;
```

Esto es lo que se me ocurre que puedas cambiar, avísame si te sirvió o no

Comment: muchísimas gracias :D